# Find all the cells in a specific row, which don't contain a number

Tags: excel, vba

How do I use the MID function within a for loop or is there a better alternative?

I'm trying to find all the cells (within a column), which don't contain a number (they are mixed numbers and text).
Then assign an interior color to those and another to the rest of the cells.

```vb
Sub FindIDs()
        
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim ColumnA As Integer
    Dim CurrentCell As String
        
    ColumnA = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
        
    For i = 2 To ColumnA
        
        CurrentCell = Cells(i, 1)
            
        For j = 1 To 75
                
            If Isnumeric(Mid(CurrentCell, j, 1)) Then
                Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(174, 240, 194)
            Else: Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(50, 200, 30)
                
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
        
End Sub
```

Comment: You want to use an `Exit For` in the IF after this line `Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(174, 240, 194)` That way if it finds a number it changes the color and stops looking other wise the color will depend on the last character only.  Also change the `75` to `Len(CurrentCell)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `75`, you can dynamically use the length of the cell's value with `len()`.

```
For j = 1 To len(CurrentCell)
```

Since you are looking to find cells that don't contain numbers, you can use a Boolean (true/false) variable to store whether the `currentCell` value has a number. Then paint the cell.

```
 Sub FindIDs()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim ColumnA As Integer
    Dim CurrentCell As String
    Dim hasNoNumber as Boolean

    ColumnA = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))

    For i = 2 To ColumnA

        CurrentCell = Cells(i, 1)
        hasNoNumber=True

        For j = 1 To len(CurrentCell)

            If Isnumeric(Mid(CurrentCell, j, 1)) Then
                'We found a number, flip the flag
                hasNoNumber=False
                'Because we found a number, then exit the for loop
                Exit For
            End If   
        Next j

        'Now set the color:
        If hasNoNumber
            Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(50, 200, 30)
        Else
            Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(174, 240, 194)
        End If
    Next i

 End Sub
```

Lastly, you might find it helpful to seperate out the logic here by making a function that tells you whether a string contains a number or not. This way, if you need to do this logic again, you can just call the function instead of Copying and Pasting the code all over the place. It also makes it easier to follow what's going in your main Subroutine.

```
Sub FindIDs()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim ColumnA As Integer

    ColumnA = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))

    For i = 2 To Column
        'Set the color based on whether there is a number in the string
        If hasNoNumber(cells(i,1).value)
            Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(50, 200, 30)
        Else
            Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(174, 240, 194)
        End If
    Next i

End Sub

Function HasNoNumber(strData As String) As Boolean
    Dim intChar As Integer

    HasNoNumber = True
    For intChar = 1 To Len(strData)
        If IsNumeric(Mid(strData, intChar, 1)) Then
            HasNumber = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next intChar

End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following:

First create a function to verify the condition for a string:

```
Function ContainsNumber(s As String) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        If IsNumeric(Mid(s, i, 1)) Then
            ContainsNumber = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

This returns `True` if the string contains a number, otherwise it returns `False` (the default Boolean value).

Then -- just use conditional formatting on the target range:

[image]

The way I got this was by entering the conditional formatting rule

```
=ContainsNumber(A1)
```

(*not* $A$1) in cell A1 and then used the Format Painter to apply it to the whole range. You should be able to tweak this for your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Also You can use [RegEx](https://blog.udemy.com/vba-regex/):

```
Sub FindIDs()

        Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
        Dim objRegex As Object

        Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        objRegex.Pattern = "[0-9]"

        LastRow = Range("A" & Columns.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Interior.Color = RGB(174, 240, 194)

        For i = 2 To LastRow
          If objRegex.Test(Cells(i, 1).Value) = False Then Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(50, 200, 30)
        Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice idea to use regular expressions

Comment: Thanks for all the lovely comments, ideas and help! I will take a look at it all and try to make my macro Work as intended :)